# DateTimePicker JQuery Plugin - Format Mask

Tags: jquery, textbox, datetimepicker, mask, datetime-format

Now, it looks like this:

[image]

But I want that it looks like this : `__ . __ . ____ __ : __` (example: `18.02.2013 18:35`)

What I already tried:

```
$(".DateTimeTextBox").datetimepicker({
    dateformat: 'd.m.Y H:i',
    timepicker:false,
    mask: true
});
```

How can I realize this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this one...

```
$('.DateTimeTextBox').datetimepicker({
    mask:'39.19.9999 29:59',
    format:'d.m.Y H:i'
});
```

if you are not getting your requirement then [Click here](http://xdsoft.net/jquery-plugins/datetimepicker/)

change mask and format which you want...
hope you will get...